# Auto Layout Challenge: Please tell me what is wrong in this case

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, constraints, size-classes

I've been trying to understand Auto Layout, but keep failing and need help.

In this test project below I wanted to align 4 squares to look good in both portrait and landscape modes on all devices. I need to know what constraints I am doing wrong.

I used views in this case.

In the first step I added equal width/size pins since all the squares were the same size.

Size of the squares were W:250 H:121.  The view container was the inferred option

[image: s13.postimg.org/74c760wvb/Equal_Wand_H.png]

In the second step I added width and height pins (cushions) between the squares.

[image: https://s22.postimg.org/msz4lui2p/Wand_H_Pins.png]

In the third step I added all the necessary outside constraints from the individual squares to the superview (leading,trailing,top to top layout, bottom to bottom layout).

[image: https://s12.postimg.org/9dk1ud95p/Outside_Constraints.png]

And finally what my constraints end up doing; they look fine in portrait but look weird/don't show in landscape.

[image: s15.postimg.org/cqavu43aj/Not_Right.png]

What am I doing wrong?  Is it a a size class issue, a constraint issue, am I completely missing certain steps, or something else?

Comment: Could you provide a picture of what you _want?_ This is so simple but you have to be very clear about what _should_ happen. You want a 2x2 grid of squares? Why not use a vertical stack view containing two horizontal stack views, each containing two squares? Now the only question remaining is: where should this outer stack view be located relative to the screen as the screen gets wider and narrow because of portrait and landscape? You have to have a plan for that, that's all.

Comment: First of all thanks for replying so fast Matt.  I just simply want 4 buttons to show on landscape mode as it did in portrait; it doesn't matter in what manner they show as I just want to learn how Auto Layout functions.  It looks like however I am going to have to learn how to use the stack views.

Maybe something like what is in this link below

https://s10.postimg.org/o5isrnpg9/Screen_Shot_2016_08_28_at_5_49_34_PM.png

Thanks!

Comment: You don't _have_ use stack views, but they make what you're describing so easy!

Answer (score 0):

In your 3.5 and 4 inch it doesnt show because you fixed the constraint to the bottom of your superView, that constraint's constant value alone is higher than the screen itself, forcing your views's height become 0 (or very small on bigger 5.5 screen like in your screenshot), for fixing this, try use less the `CONSTANT` value, instead, make the `constant` become 0, and change the `Multiplier` value on those you want to make it scale with the super view (in your case is the constraint to bottom)

Another option is change the priority of the bottom constraint to lower, and give one of the view a `height` constraint (`Relation` set to either `equal` or `greater than or equal`) and it will work